# ColdFusion unit test frameworks

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, mxunit

As a related sub-question - are there any CF unit test frameworks that support or make it easier to use mocks/stubs?

The 2 that I spotted in a quick google that look the most promising are MXUnit and CFUnit.  Are there others, and which one(s) have the widest adoption and active development?  Enough questions crammed into one?

Basically I want to make a good choice.

*edit* Note that at the time of writing the question originally, MXUnit was the go-to and TestBox wouldn't be on github for a few years yet.  See comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: See http://carehart.org/cf411/#cfmlunittest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TestBox is a new xUnit and BDD style framework that is compatible with MXUnit and comes with MockBox which is a full mocking and stubbing library.  Both of these are actively developed and professionally supported by Ortus Solutions.

https://testbox.ortusbooks.com/introduction/installing-testbox

https://testbox.ortusbooks.com/mocking/mockbox/installing-mockbox

Comment: Hey Brad!  Thanks for adding this one.  This is one I recently learned of and I'm excited to learn more about it.  Once I get a chance to dig in and update comments here (and on the accepted answer) with my experience.  I may even change this to the accepted answer :)

Comment: No Problem.  MXUnit has basically stopped all new development for quite some time now.  Please join the main ColdBox Google Group if you have questions or need help:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/coldbox
Here is a video introduction to TestBox:
http://blog.coldbox.org/blog/coldbox-connection-video-intro-to-testbox
And here are live TestBox samples you can run in your browser:
http://runnable.com/UsyCKoc0i3w-AADF/testbox-samples-for-coldfusion-cfml-railo-mxunit-bdd-tdd-and-xunit

Comment: Isn't TestBox compatible only with CF 10 though?

Comment: That is not correct.  You can do XUnit and MXUnit compat test with TestBox on CF9. It is the BDD-style tests specifically that require closures and therefore can only be done on Railo and CF10. It's all explained here in our docs: http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/TestBox.cfm#System_Requirements

Comment: @BradWood Links are dead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I updated the answer to have the correct links.  I can't edit my comment above, so here is the new link for that:
https://testbox.ortusbooks.com/introduction/overview/system-requirements

Answer (score 15):

Pretty sure that the only CF unit test framework still in active development is [MXUnit](https://github.com/mxunit/).

Check out MockBox (also in active development) for support in using mocks/stubs.
http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/MockBox.cfm

Edit: Be sure to follow the MXUnit google group.  http://groups.google.com/group/mxunit/topics

Comment: MXUnit supports mocking as well through MightMock - http://wiki.mxunit.org/display/default/Mocking+and+Stubbing. If you'd rather swap that out for Mockbox though then they give you the ability to do that also - http://wiki.mxunit.org/display/default/Using+External+Mocking+Frameworks

Comment: And there is RocketUnit http://rocketboots.com.au/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=E565633C-E081-51EF-A7F883614F752942

Comment: Awesome - good information.  That's the beauty of SO - someone in my particular situation looking for a similar answer will hopefully also benefit from knowing about things like MightMock, Mockbox, RocketUnit, and Selenium (see mz_01's answer) where just googling might only quickly turn up MXUnit and CFUnit.  Thanks all :)

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to reflect the current state of things. It does look like MXUnit hasn't had more than a small handful of commits in recent years, where TestBox is being actively developed.  Hopefully that helps anyone starting out with testing in CF.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget http://github.com/bobsilverberg/CFSelenium

Comment: I've very little experience with testing in Selenium or CFSelenium but I'm curious - where does mocking play a role in those?

Comment: Isn't Selenium for user interface testing rather than unit testing?

Comment: Projects like Selenium or QUnit can also be used to test any Javascript-based business logic (e.g. client-side stage of your input validation).

And don't forget that it's possible to combine server-side testing (e.g. MXUnit) and client-side testing (e.g. Selenium). Think of stuff like testing AJAX requests against CF webservices.